# Python - store results from multiprocessing in a global dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataset with 32 variables and ~900 observations that I want to test in a multiple linear regression model (statsmodel ols). I want to see which ones work best together - I'm basically brute forcing this as the relationship isn't clear to anyone. Unfortunately its taking hours to complete.
I decided to try multiprocessing to speed it up. for each combination of variables the script will:

- build a statement
- Perform a linear regression
- extract summary values (p / Bic / Rsquared)
- Store them in a dataframe

I have te first 3 working but when I try to store the in the dataframe and output at the end it returns nothing. Any ideas? I have declared the dataframe as global.
I'm confident that function works as I use a modified version of it in the original model.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statistics import mean
from statistics import median
from multiprocessing import Pool
import datetime
import os

#Create the dataframe
inLoc='C:\\temp\\retailer_cost\\'
inName='raw_data_v1_2.csv'
inFile = inLoc + inName
df=pd.read_csv(inFile)

#Create the dataframe to store the summary results in 
summaryDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['modelID','statement','num_vars','BIC','AIC','RSQ','RSQ_ADJ','CONDITION','AVG_PVALUE','MEDIAN_PVALUE','POSITIVE_VALUES'])

combList = [['a','b','c','d','e'],
            ['a','b','c','d',],
            ['a','b','c','e'],
            ['a','b','d','e'],
            ['a','c','d','e'],
            ['b','c','d','e']]

################################################################
#Function
################################################################

def processor(combin):
    date_time = str(datetime.datetime.now().time())
    #Declare SummaryDF as global 
    global summaryDF
    stmt,interceptOut = createStmt('adjusted_value', combin)
    print(stmt)
    mod = smf.ols(formula=stmt, data=df)
    results = mod.fit()
    modID = str(date_time) + '_' + str(interceptOut)
    avg = mean(list(results.pvalues))
    mdn = median(list(results.pvalues))
    #Extract coefficients
    pVals = list(dict(results.pvalues).items())
    coeffs = list(dict(results.params).items())
    tVals = list(dict(results.tvalues).items())
    #Create the record to add
    summOut = {'modelID': modID,  'statement': stmt, 'num_vars': str(len(combin)), 'BIC': str(results.bic) ,'AIC': str(results.aic) ,'RSQ': str(results.rsquared) ,'RSQ_ADJ': str(results.rsquared_adj),'CONDITION': str(results.condition_number),'AVG_PVALUE': str(avg),'MEDIAN_PVALUE': str(mdn)}
summaryDF = summaryDF.append(summOut, ignore_index = True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()                         
    pool.map(processor, combList)

#Produces nothing
summaryDF.to_csv('c:\\temp\\olsModelOut.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Multiprocessing runs your functions in their own process; processes don’t share memory space with each other; your processes each are updating their own version of the global variable. You’ll have to explicitly return/send the results from each process to the main process. Note that the overheads of sending data to/fro between processes can exceed the advantage of running multiple processes.

Comment: Thanks Barry, I'm wide open to suggestions! Is there a better solution? Im quite a novice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `summOut` from `processor` function and store values in a list (here `data`). After that, you can convert the list of `summOut` to your dataframe `summaryDF`. You can do something like that:

```
def processor(combin):
    ...
    return summOut


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        data = pool.map(processor, combList)
        summaryDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Hi Corralien
Thank you for your solution! Will this just overwrite the summaryDF over and over?
Would summaryDF = summaryDF.append(data) work?

Comment: No, `summaryDF` will be created once at the end of computation. Besides, the first declaration of `summaryDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ModelID',...])` in your code is useless in this case.